# How to marshall a Node or Document field?

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm trying to marshall a class with a field like this:

```
@XmlElement
private Document content;
```

*(JAXB complains that it can't marshal an interface, but that's beside the point.)*

**I want the DOM tree represented by `content` to be imported and inserted into the result document**, so I'd end up with something like:

```xml
<stuff>
    <myObject>
        <content>
            (root node of Document value of content field here)
        </content>
...
```

Is this possible and if so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the field/property type from `Document` to `Object` to get rid of that interface related exception.  When JAXB doesn't know what type of object to build it will treat it as a DOM.

### Domain Model

**Root**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private Object content;

    public Object getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(Object content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

**input.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <content>
        <dom-1>
            <dom-2>
                <dom-3/>
            </dom-2>
        </dom-1>
    </content>
</root>
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum18906595/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Element element = (Element) root.getContent();
        System.out.println(element.getNodeName());
    }

}
```

**Output**

Here the root element is the element corresponding to the property and not nested document.

```
content
```

---

### UPDATE

Below is a way that you could leverage `@XmlElementWrapper` and `@XmlAnyElement` to get the behaviour that you are looking for.  I have used `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` to keep all the magic in the field without having to change property at all.

**Root**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="content")
    @XmlAnyElement
    private List<Object> content;

    public Object getContent() {
        if(null == content || content.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return content.get(0);
    }

    public void setContent(Object content) {
        if(null == content) {
            this.content = null;
        } else {
            if(null == this.content) {
                this.content = new ArrayList<Object>(1);
            }
            this.content.set(0, content);
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the new output from running the same demo code.  The element name now is what you are expecting.

```
dom-1
```